# Get Android predefined string

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm tying to get predefined Android strings (from android sdk):

I do can get strings like: `android.R.string.ok` and `android.R.string.cancel`.
But I cannot get `android.R.string.activity_resolver_use_always` and `android.R.string.activity_resolver_use_once`
Getting error 'Cannot resolve symbol' in Android Studio even though I can see all the strings id's in `android.R` file.

using: `context.getString(android.R.string.activity_resolver_use_always)`

Is there other way to get those strings?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: And now show us the XML file where you defined all of the things that you're actually trying to grab.

Comment: Try to use : context.getResources().getString(R.string.activity_resolver_use_always);

Comment: @yash786 the problem is that R.string.activity_resolver_‌​use_always nor android.R.string.activity_resolver_‌​use_always is not recognized by the IDE.

Comment: What makes you think you should have access to those strings in the first place? Where did you see them used?

Comment: You should not rely on those per-defined strings. Because they can change/unavailable based on api level. Better you use your own strings.

Answer (score 1):

That's the answer:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("activity_resolver_use_once", "string", "android");
final String always = getString(resId);
```